# Which dragons can live in the Gemstone Island?

Tags: dragonvale

I'm not exactly sure which dragons can live in the Gemstone Island.  Can someone enlighten me, please?

Comment: The below answers mostly cover it, but I'd also point out a small "diamondish" icon appears in the detail view for dragons which are of type "Gemstone" and capable of inhabiting the Gemstone Island habitats.

Comment: They now have a thirteenth gemstone dragon - Jade. On the island there are only four habitats - 3 dragons on each, equating to 12 slots. You need one of your gemstone dragons to not be on display if you have all 13 of them.

Answer (score 2):

The Gemstone Island habitats can host any of the Gemstone Dragons.

Currently, these are fourteen of these:

- Amethyst Dragon,
- Aquamarine Dragon,
- Diamond Dragon,
- Emerald Dragon,
- Garnet Dragon,
- Jade Dragon,
- Lapis Dragon,
- Opal Dragon,
- Pearl Dragon,
- Peridot Dragon,
- Ruby Dragon,
- Saphire Dragon,
- Topaz Dragon, and
- Turquoise Dragon

Answer (score 1):

Gemstone Dragons live in the Gemstone Island Habitats, where they will bring you gems instead of gold.

The first set of Gemstone Dragons ended in April of 2013 with a total of 12 dragons, and each corresponds with the [birthstone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthstones) of a particular month.  The first set of 12 can only be bred during the month they were first introduced.

Backflip introduced a second set of Gemstone dragons, starting with [Jade](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/how-do-i-breed-a-jade-dragon-in-dragonvale/) in May of 2013.  These dragons have a three month breeding window instead of one.

All Gemstone dragons are extremely rare and can be tricky to breed, and thus far there is only ever one combination that can be used to breed a particular gemstone dragon.

The DragonVale Wikia has a [complete list of gemstones](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Gemstone_Dragons) and you can determine which is/are current by consulting a list of the currently limited dragons, like [this one](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/dragonvale-current-limited-dragons/).